# How to keep ble android application running in background?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, android-background, bluetooth-gatt

I am working on the android application. In this application i have to connect to the ble device. I want the application connected to the ble device when the application is in background .

Answer (score 4):

The answer is to have at least one Foreground Service https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground in your process that uses BLE. That will make Android keep your process alive.

Comment: So that means the bluetooth work does not need to be inside the service, but the service just needs to run "next" to the bluetooth listeners etc.. , so the app stays alive?

Comment: Correct. The same process that has BluetoothGatt objects needs to have a Foreground Service running.