# How to Bluetooth LE background connection?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager, android-background, android-ble

Sorry for my bad English.

## Context

My main goal is to build a electronic lock, the key would be a phone connected in BLE. The proximity of the phone must unlock the lock.

## What I want to do

A application who this connect automatically at a BLE devices when the phone is a proximity.
So,the application need run in background. But I am a begin in android/Kotlin. I read the official trainings of google and I was thinking using WorkManager.

## The problems

- I don't understand the behavior of the BLE with WorkManager when the application is closed by the user.
- In the `doWork()` function of  a Worker, I nothing to put that takes CPU time. Just a setup a callback BLE (with `BluetoothDevice.connectGatt()`). So, the `doWork()` is fast executed.
- If there is a device connected and the application is closed by the user, this device is automatically disconnected.

## BLE connection

I don't have a problem about the BLE connection. For this, I use `BluetoothDevice.connectGatt()` [(view doc)](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice#connectGatt(android.content.Context,%20kotlin.Boolean,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback)) with `autoConnect` parameter at true. The callback in correctly called when a device is connected or the connection is lost `BluetoothGattCallback.onConnectionStateChange()` [(view doc)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20int,%20int))

## WorkManager behavior

To try to understand the behavior of WorkManager, I added 1min delay `Thread.sleep(60000)` in `doWork()` function of a `Worker`. And here is what I noticed:

1. When `Worker` is running (last minute in my case) and `WorkManager.cancelAllWorkByTag()` is called:

   - The `onStopped()` of the `Worker` is called but the worker continue to run.
2. When `Worker` is running and the BLE device is connected and the application is closed by de the user:

   - The `Worker` is stopped
   - The BLE device lost connection
   - The `Worker` is resurrect after a minute and the BLE callback (connection/disconnection) work again, even after end of run of `Worker`.

## My Worker code (not very clean)

```kotlin
class BleWorker(
    appContext: Context,
    workerParams: WorkerParameters
) : Worker(appContext, workerParams) {

    private val bluetoothManager: BluetoothManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
    private var bleDevice: BluetoothDevice? = null
    private var bluetoothGatt: BluetoothGatt? = null


    private val SERV_UUID = UUID.fromString("44707b20-3459-11ee-aea4-0800200c9a66")
    private val CHAR_UUID_UNLOCK = UUID.fromString("44707b21-3459-11ee-aea4-0800200c9a66")
    private val CHAR_UUID_STATE = UUID.fromString("44707b22-3459-11ee-aea4-0800200c9a66")

    private var service: BluetoothGattService? = null
    private var charUnlock: BluetoothGattCharacteristic? = null
    private var charState: BluetoothGattCharacteristic? = null

    init {
        Log.i("learnBle","BleWorker ($id:$tags) init" )
    }

    protected fun finalize() {
        Log.i("learnBle","BleWorker ($id) finalize" )
    }

    override fun onStopped() {
        Log.i("learnBle","BleWorker ($id) onStopped" )
        super.onStopped()
    }


    override fun doWork(): Result {
        var result: Result
        try {
            Log.i("learnBle","BleWorker ($id) doWork started" )

            bleDevice = bluetoothManager.adapter.bondedDevices.find {
                it.address == BLE_ADD
            }

            if (bleDevice != null)
            {
                bluetoothGatt = bleDevice!!.connectGatt(
                    applicationContext,
                    true,
                    gattCallback_auto2)
            }
            else
            {
                Log.i("learnBle","BleWorker ($id) doWork no device bonded !" )
                Result.failure()
            }

            Thread.sleep(60000)
            Log.i("learnBle","BleWorker ($id) doWork ended" )
            result = Result.success()
        } catch (e: Exception)
        {
            Log.i("learnBle","BleWorker ($id) doWork ended with FAILURE" )
            result = Result.failure()
        }

        return result
    }


    private val gattCallback_auto2: BluetoothGattCallback = object : BluetoothGattCallback() {
        override fun onConnectionStateChange(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int, newState: Int) {
            super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState)

            if (    status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS
                &&  newState == BluetoothGatt.STATE_CONNECTED) {

                val ret = gatt!!.discoverServices()
                Log.i("learnBle","BleWorker:Callback ($id) auto discover services starting:$ret" )
            }
            else {
                Log.i("learnBle","BleWorker:Callback ($id) auto Connexion failed !" )
            }
        }

        override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int) {
            super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status)

            // Note: Here gatt == bluetoothGatt
            val services = gatt?.services

            service = gatt?.getService(SERV_UUID)
            charUnlock = service?.getCharacteristic(CHAR_UUID_UNLOCK)
            charState = service?.getCharacteristic(CHAR_UUID_STATE)

            // Unlock
            if (charUnlock != null) {
                val value = byteArrayOf(0x01)
                gatt?.writeCharacteristic(
                    charUnlock!!,
                    value,
                    BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT)

                Log.i("learnBle","BleWorker:Callback ($id) unloked !" )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Can you help me ?

- `WorkManager` is it the good solution for my problem ?
- To run a `Worker` in background (after close the application), I should replace `Thread.sleep(60000)` by something to wait infinite time. It is weird. How to do otherwise ?
- How to avoid the disconnection with the BLE device when de user close the application ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep ble android application running in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46109365/how-to-keep-ble-android-application-running-in-background)

Comment: Use autoConnect=true to automatically reconnect to the device when the connection drops. Then use a Foreground Service to keep the app alive.

Comment: Here I suggest please use the foreground service to keep app running in background or killed from the phone recent task area. The operation you are looking will not going to manage by work manager. To implement stable functionality, foreground would be the great option

Answer (score 0):

Android and iOS can trigger app functions when the system detects BLE advertisements. Check android library for this: [Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html)

And yes, you don't need to use background services or smth like that